# Extract, filter and match three letters from the given arguments and predict the name

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Case 1: rank1_naming

This function takes two arguments

- list_proteins_pattern_available
- best_match_protein_name

> Objective: Extract the three letter pattern from the both arguments.
>   Match the pattern and keep only the matched items. Extract the numbers
>   from `list_proteins_pattern_available` and also sort it. Find the
>   maximum number from the collected numbers and add `1` to get the next
>   number.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Can you point ways to improve this script?

```
import re

def case_rank1_naming(list_proteins_pattern_available, best_match_protein_name):
    #This will store the list of numbers
    available_list_numbers = []

    #extract the three letter pattern
    protein_pattern = re.search(r"[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}", best_match_protein_name)
    protein_pattern = protein_pattern.group()

    #extract the numbers
    for name in list_proteins_pattern_available:
        pattern = re.search(r"[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}\d{1,3}", name)
        number = re.search(r"\d{1,3}", pattern.group())
        available_list_numbers.append(number.group())

    #Convert all the string numbers to integers
    available_list_numbers = [int(x) for x in available_list_numbers]

    #Sort the available number. Just realized I use two times sort function.
    available_list_numbers.sort()

    # Sort the available number, get the maximum number and add one to get next number
    # Example: result will be 50
    primary_number_prediction = int(max(sorted(available_list_numbers))) + 1

    #Add the protein pattern, the next predicted number and 'Aa1' at the suffix
    predicted_name = protein_pattern + str(primary_number_prediction) + 'Aa1'

    return predicted_name


list_proteins_pattern_available = ['Xpp1Aa1', 'Xpp2Aa1', 'Xpp35Aa1', 'Xpp35Ab1', 'Xpp35Ac1', 'Xpp35Ba1', 'Xpp36Aa1', 'Xpp49Aa1', 'Xpp49Ab1']

best_match_protein_name = 'Xpp35Ba1'

predicted_name = case_rank1_naming(list_proteins_pattern_available, best_match_protein_name)

print(predicted_name)
#Xpp50Aa1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show an example implementation first, and then describe it:

```
from typing import Iterable
import re


def case_rank1_naming(proteins_available: Iterable[str], best_match_protein_name: str) -> str:
    # extract the three-letter pattern
    protein_pattern = re.search(r"[A-Z][a-z]{2}", best_match_protein_name).group()

    # extract the numbers
    best_number = max(
        int(re.search(r"[A-Z][a-z]{2}(\d{1,3})", name)[1])
        for name in proteins_available
    )

    # Add the protein pattern, the next predicted number and 'Aa1' at the suffix
    return f'{protein_pattern}{best_number + 1}Aa1'


def main():
    proteins_available = (
        'Xpp1Aa1', 'Xpp2Aa1', 'Xpp35Aa1', 'Xpp35Ab1', 'Xpp35Ac1',
        'Xpp35Ba1', 'Xpp36Aa1', 'Xpp49Aa1', 'Xpp49Ab1'
    )
    best_match_protein_name = 'Xpp35Ba1'
    predicted_name = case_rank1_naming(proteins_available, best_match_protein_name)
    assert predicted_name == 'Xpp50Aa1'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- Add type hints to better-define your function signature
- Don't write `{1}` in a regex - you can just drop it
- Call `max` immediately on a generator rather than making and sorting a list
- Shorten your variable names. Especially don't include the type of the variable in its name. Type hints and appropriate pluralization will cover you instead.
- Use f-strings
- Have a `main` function
- In `main`, use a tuple for `proteins_available` instead of a list because it doesn't need to mutate

Comment: you are on a roll :)

Comment: Thank you. I will go through it and understand.

Comment: Why this step assert predicted_name == 'Xpp50Aa1'. In many cases we don't know the predicted name. right? Is this for testing?

Comment: Yes, it's only for testing. You'll definitely want to leave that out in general program use, and move it to a unit test.